# Get Table Name, Column Name, Data Type & Character Maximum Lenght mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in MySQL called "Test Database" and I want to create a query to get all database's columns with the following characteristics:

1. First column - Table name
2. Second column - Column name
3. Third column - Type
4. Forth column - Maximum length

I used the following queries separately to get what i want:

1. Get Table Name:

   `Select Table_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables`
2. Get Columns Name:

   `Select Column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns`
3. Get Column Type:

   `Select Data_Type from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns`
4. Get Columns Size:

   `Select Character_Maximum_Length from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns`

But I did not manage to merge this into one query to get the below result:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put more than one column in a SELECT statement..

```
Select Table_Name, Column_Name, Data_Type, Character_Maximum_Length 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
```

Use AS if you want to rename the columns you see (`SELECT table_name AS "Table Name" ...`. I'd recommend not putting spaces in them though

Answer (score 0):

If that is the entire table, then you could simplify your query easily as:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
```

this will get all columns that you need. 
If you want to be more specific you could try this variant:

```
SELECT Table_Name AS TableName, Column_Name as ColumnName, Data_Type as 
DataType, Character_Maximum_Length as Character_Maximum_Length FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
```

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

To get Table Schema, Table name, column name, column datatype, column length in the order of table and column ordinal position:

```
Select TABLE_SCHEMA,Table_Name, Column_Name, Data_Type, Character_Maximum_Length 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns --<where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'>
order by TABLE_SCHEMA, Table_Name, ORDINAL_POSITION
```